# Cannot find a document in the search by this search key "13-003914"

Tags: search

I am using sharepoint 2007. I have a document in a document library. This is the url of the document:

http://myCompany.com/sub/12345/Drawings/13-003914.tif

I try to search on this documents, but the search cannot find it. I did a full crawl. I try also "13-003914*" but didnt give any results.

I have also another document.

http://myCompany.com/sub/12345/Drawings/E032426-003.TIF

When I search on "E032426-003" I can find it in the search results.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Check the Crawl Log in Central Administration. Make sure both documents were indexed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to search for files with the tif/tiff extension, you need to make sure that you enable the "Windows TIFF filter" from the server manager features.

This blogpost explains the steps to take. Make sure to follow the steps and you should be good to go.

[Search TIFF files in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint__cloud/archive/2012/09/19/search-tiff-files-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Some additional information from Microsoft about the filter.

[Windows TIFF IFilter Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd834685.aspx)